# Enable Save button in you tube video web page through Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am  writing to Description text box of a youtube video through VBA.
I am able to send information to the text box through VBA.
But unless i press enter in the description text box or write manually the save button of the youtube page is not getting enabled and hence it is not saving the page with my new contents.
Kindly tell me how to press enter specifically in the description text box through VBA.

Following is the lines of code i am using for

vba code for writing to description text box

```
Cells(k, 27).Value = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("yt-uix-form-input-textarea video-settings-description")(0).innertext
```

vba code for clicking on save button

```
ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("yt-uix-button-content")(0).Click
```

I dont have any issues with the above code. I need the code for pressing enter in the description text box with the classname `yt-uix-button-content` in addition to the text i am sending through vba

html of the youtube video page when save button is not enabled

"Save changes"

html of the youtube page when save button is enabled

"Save changes"

[html difference between save enabled and save disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVbKT.jpg)

[Picture with Save button not enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZYWD.jpg)

[Picture with save  button enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GKvJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I would try [Selenium Basic](http://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/) and then after doing the equivalent finding of the element

```
Dim keys As New Selenium.keys, ele As WebElement

Set ele = driver.FindElementByClass("yt-uix-form-input-textarea video-settings-description")
'Do what ever else to set value
ele.SendKeys keys.Enter
```